# How to stop maven-remote-resources-plugin from overwritting resources

Tags: java, maven, maven-remote-resources

in my application i have many modules with resources.

```
project
|
└───moduleA
|   |
│   └───resources
│       │
│       └───fileA
|
└───moduleB
|   |
│   └───resources
│   
└───moduleC
|   |
|   └───resources
|       │
|       |───fileA
|       └───fileB
|
...
```

In `moduleA` and `moduleB` i use `maven-remote-resources` plugin to include resources (fileA and fileB) from `moduleC`. If the file with a given name exists in a moduleA or B, it should not be overwritten with the one from `moduleC`. Files get overwritten by default. How to configure the plugin to avoid that?

Comment: Why do you need resources from another module? Furthermore have you put the resources for tests or for production code?

Comment: I have about 90 modules which need to share a specific files. Instead of create 90 files we can create one file and share it, to make it easier to maintain. However, there are modules that contain their own version of the file and in their case, file gets overridden. Those modules are separated simple apps, and those files are bash scripts that are packed into assembly .zip using maven-assembly-plugin and contain scripts that run those modules.

Comment: Are those files test resources or production resources?

Comment: Production resources

Comment: Than you have them on classpath why do you need to copy them?